# PhpRedis -- While getting keys from redis db through phpredis always getting false but from redis-cli getting keys

Tags: php, redis, phpredis

I am stuck at this problem from last 2 days. Please help me out.

I am writting a code to get the keys from a database in redis. I am using php redis library but this code is working on system but not in the other. While getting the keys through CLI i am getting all the keys in that db.

The code is here :-

```
function getValues() {

    $redis =  new Redis();
    $redis->Connect(HOST,6379);
    $redis->select(1);
    var_dump($redis->KEYS('*'));
    return $redis->zRange("KEY",0,-1,true);
}
```

Also if i comment 
`var_dump($redis->KEYS('*'));` it returns me the values in that `KEY` but if i do not comment the above line, `return $redis->zRange("KEY",0,-1,true);`  returns `bool(false)`.

Please help

Comment: What does `TYPE KEY` return in the CLI? Could it be that your key named `KEY` isn't a Sorted Set? (P.S. calling a key `KEY` is key to loosing your sanity ;))

Comment: The KEY keyword is for reference that i will be putting the original key name in the place of "KEY"

Comment: What is the key's type?

Comment: Key is of Sorted sets data type

Comment: Please use the code format for inline snippets, it is more readable than bold format. Edited it for you.